# Give a unique id to the first three elements and repeat for next three

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have this line of code which generates posts from a certain post type:

```
    <div class="row">

        <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'cases',
                'posts_per_page' => 3,
                offset => 2
            );
            $the_query1 = new WP_Query( $args );
            if ( $the_query1 -> have_posts() ):
            while ( $the_query1->have_posts() ): $the_query1->the_post();
        ?>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="case-container">
                <div class="case-info-triple">
                    <h4 id="case-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                    <p id="case-type"><?php the_field('case_type') ?></p>
                    <p id="case-desc"><?php $caseteaser = get_field('case_content', false, false); echo substr($caseteaser, 0, 200); ?></p>
                    <img src="Diensten - zeo9-arrow.png" /><a href="<?php the_field('case_url') ?>">Bekijk deze case</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();?>
        <?php endif;?>

    </div>
```

That generates this:

[image]

However, I would like the every three '`case-info-triple`' elements to have their own unique id. For example, `<div class="case-info-triple-1">`, `<div class="case-info-triple-2">`, `<div class="case-info-triple-3">` and then again, `<div class="case-info-triple-1">`, `<div class="case-info-triple-2">` etc etc.

See corresponding source:

[image]

We show for now 3 posts per page, but we will change it to 9 in the future. Basically, every first, second and third info element has its own color and I need them to have a unique id so I can style them with css.

How to approach this?

Comment: Does the modulus solution below work for you?

Comment: Yes, it seems to do the trick. I really simplistic approach in PHP. Impressive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before your while loop, initialize a variable:

```
$cnt = 0;
```

Then inside your while loop you can put this:

```
$classID = $cnt++%3;
```

to increment the counter and then modulus by 3.  You can adjust this for any number of columns.  Using 3 as your modulus will produce a number between 0 and 2.  Then use the classID here:

```
<div class="case-info-triple<?php echo '-'.$classID; ?>">
```

Or you can skip the `$cnt` variable and do the increment at the same time that you echo the classID, like this:

```
$classID = 0;

while($classID <= 5) { ?>
    <div class="case-info-triple<?php echo '-'.$classID++%3; ?>">text</div>
<?php }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many option but you use a counter variable and add that in class name to make it unique ,for example in your code you can do like this:-

```
<div class="row">

<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'cases',
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        offset => 2
    );
    $the_query1 = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $the_query1 -> have_posts() ):
    $id = 1;
    while ( $the_query1->have_posts() ): $the_query1->the_post();
    $infoClassName = "case-info-triple-"+$id;
?>

<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="<?php echo $infoClassName; ?>">
        <div class="case-info-triple">
            <h4 id="case-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
            <p id="case-type"><?php the_field('case_type') ?></p>
            <p id="case-desc"><?php $caseteaser = get_field('case_content', false, false); echo substr($caseteaser, 0, 200); ?></p>
            <img src="Diensten - zeo9-arrow.png" /><a href="<?php the_field('case_url') ?>">Bekijk deze case</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php $id++; ?>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you add arguments to your array that indicates rows (3 rows with 3 posts)?

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'cases',
  'posts_per_row' => 3,
  'rows_per_page' => 3,
```

Then move your html around the script so you can insert an `if... elseif... else` section to automate naming your `<div class="case-info-triple-1">`, `-2`, or `-3`, based on which row of posts it is in.